# ItemSource as DataTable

Tags: wpf

I have my DataGrid and I have all results inside DataTable.

```
DataTable dt = MakeTable();

<DataGrid Height="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,1,0,0" Name="resultDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="475" ReadOnly="True">
```

I remember in Windows Form I was able to do something like:

```
dt.ItemSource = dt;
```

and it was working fine, but in WPF I am getting error: Cannot convert datasource DataTable to target IEnumerable.

Column names is always **DIFFERENT**, I cannot build a table manually!

How would I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable don't support ienumrable. so you need to cast your datatable into eighter ilist or enumrable source.

try this.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
resultDataGrid.ItemsSource =  dt.DefaultView
```

also set AutoGenerateColumns=true if you are not setting column in advance.